# Is there a way to transform high fidelity design into LOW fidelity On Figma?

Tags: user-interface, figma

Good afternoon,

I have high fidelity ui design frames on figma. I want to send it to several developers so that they can give me a proposal of how much will cost to code the pages.

For intelectual protection purposes, I don’t want a lot o people see the high fidelity  frameS. So I want to show a draft/minimum for them to be able to give me a offer for the job. That’s why I want to convert a high fidelity ui design into low fidelity.

Is there a automated or semiautomated way to convert high fidelity ui design into low fidelity? Thank you!